# Winston error logger displays error message twice

Tags: node.js, winston

I am trying to print the the error message and error stack in Winston.

Here is my configuration

```
export const logger = (service: string): Logger =>
  createLogger({
    level: level,
    format: combine(
      errors({ stack: true }),
      timestamp(),
      splat(),
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? json()
        : format.printf((info) => {
            if (info && info.level === 'error') {
              info.message = `${info.message} ${info.stack}`;
            }
            return colorizer.colorize(
              info.level,
              `${info.timestamp} - ${info.level}: ${JSON.stringify(
                info.message
              )}`
            );
          })
    ),
    defaultMeta: { service },
    transports: [
      new transports.Console(),
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
    exceptionHandlers: [new transports.Console()],
  });
```

In one function I do

```
return Promise.reject(
  new Error('No customer found with this email')
);
```

The logger shows

```
Unexpected message handler failure: No customer found with this email Error: No customer found with this email\n    at /Users/xxxx/projects/xxx/packages/package/src/someFile.ts:59:7\n
```

is there a way not to log the message error twice?

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the message when you append `info.message` and `info.stack`. `info.stack` already has the message appended so the new `info.message` is getting the error message duplicated.

Just use the `info.stack` and it will display what you need.

As a side note the `info.stack` also has the log level appended, so you may need to remove the `info.level` as well.

```js
// In your case, this is the value of info.stack.
info.stack = "Error: No customer found with this email\n    at /Users/xxxx/projects/xxx/packages/package/src/someFile.ts:59:7\n"
```